# Have status bar's height to be 100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the status bar's height to be 100% of the container. I tried giving it fixed height but even when the height increases... the text on the new line appears below the status bar rather than beside it.

Code:

```css
.list {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px #666666 solid;
  width: 250px;
}
.list > .status-bar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span class="status-bar">&nbsp;</span>Test 1 Test 1Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1dkcjgua/)**

Comment: Is the end result to have the status-bar always occupy the left side and have the text to the right?

Comment: yes exactly @LGSon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to go with `flexbox`, it will give you more *flexibility* and *control* of the layout.

```css
.list {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px #666666 solid;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
}
.list .status-bar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.list .status-text {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="status-bar"></div>
  <div class="status-text">Test 1 Test 1Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1</div>
</div>
```

With vertically centered text

```css
.list {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px #666666 solid;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
}
.list .status-bar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 40px 20px;
}
.list .status-text {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="status-bar"></div>
  <div class="status-text">Test 1 Test 1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Float the `status-bar` to the left to allow the text to wrap around it.
2. Then apply clearfix for float by clearing the float using this:

   ```
   .list:after{
     clear: both;
     content: '';
     display: block;
   }
   ```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
.list {
  padding:0;
  border: 1px #666666 solid;
  width: 250px;
}

.list > .status-bar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  padding:20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  float: left;
}

.list:after{
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span class="status-bar">&nbsp;</span>Test 1 Test 1Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1
  
</div>
```

Comment: One question... How can I make the text vertically aligned too with your changes?

Comment: @user4756836 just saw your comment here... seems you have already got the solution in LGSon 's answer :) In this answer for vertically aligning the inline element, it needs some `inline-block` tactics and specifying widths...

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the text is longer than the width of your container. It is wrapping and going below your status bar. You can fix this by adding the CSS `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.list` class.

```css
.list {
  padding:0;
  border: 1px #666666 solid;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap; /* added */
}

.list > .status-bar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  padding:20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span class="status-bar">&nbsp;</span>Test 1 Test 1Test 1 Test 1 Test 1 Test 1
</div>
```

The text will overflow to the right (which you may want to handle in some way - maybe `overflow:hidden`), but it does solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Quick decision:

```
.list {
  display: table;
}

.list > .status-bar {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Your desired result: https://jsfiddle.net/1dkcjgua/2/